# call external form in ajax callback

Tags: forms, blocks, ajax

I have two forms (A & B) in custom module. Form A containing three fields(each field is dependent drop down) and Form B containing only one field (markup field to show data).
The problem is that when I change either field from Form A then its dependent fields within form A an also markup field from Form B should be updated via ajax.

Here is the callback function used in FORM A. After calling, it returns fields from Form A. But I want it also return field of FORM B. 
(One Callback to render two forms at a time)

```
<?php
 function mymodule_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
     return array(
        '#type' => 'ajax',
        '#commands' => array(
            ajax_command_replace("#key_wrapper", render($form['keys'])),
            ajax_command_replace("#display_wrapper", render($form['display'])),
        ),
     );
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with help of little js snippet. I attached a js file to form and got my charming work.

```
(function($, Drupal)
 {
  function selectAListener()
   {
   // $("edit-term") is our select element in form A
    $("#edit-term").once("select-a-listener", function()
     {
     // $(this) refers to $("edit-term")
      $(this).change(function()
       {
        // $("edit-termh") is our select element in form B
        // $(this) refers to $("edit-term")
        // We need to set the value of the select element in
        // form B, then call $.change() which will trigger the #ajax
        $("#edit-termh").val($(this).val()).change();
       });
     });
   }

   function selectBListener()
   {
    $("#edit-chld").once("select-b-listener", function()
     {
      // $(this) refers to $("edit-select-a")
      $(this).change(function()
       {
        // $("edit-chldh") is our select element in form B
        // $(this) refers to $("edit-chld")
        // We need to set the value of the select element in
        // form B, then call $.change() which will trigger the #ajax
        $("#edit-chldh").val($(this).val()).change();
       });
     });
    }
Drupal.behaviors.formExample = {
      attach:function()
      {
       selectAListener();
       selectBListener();
       }

}}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use..

```
function custom_conditional_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['form1']['drupal_love'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Do you love Drupal?'),
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array('yes' => t('Yes'), 'no' => t('No')),
  );
  $form['form1']['how_much_love'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Great! Tell us more:'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="drupal_love"]' => array('value' => 'yes'),
      ),
      'required' => array(
        ':input[name="drupal_love"]' => array('value' => 'yes'),
      ),
    ),
  );
  $form['form1']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: My two forms place in two blocks, then how this code will be helpful ???

Comment: @WaQaRAli you should have (and should now edit your question to) included that information plus anything else you haven't already mentioned. We only know what you provide, and if you don't provide enough information, we are left guessing which will cause an answer that may be correct, but not useful in your situation

Comment: @Geoff now check you can see some information.

Answer (score 0):

you could look at implementing something like [Block Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_refresh)

```
Block Refresh allows an administrator to configure a block to refresh it's content via 3 different methods: automatically via a timer (eg every 30 seconds) , manually via a 'refresh' link, and once on page load.

Block Refresh uses jQuery/AJAX so the refresh happens "behind-the-scenes".

Block refresh can be handy to serve fresh content in certain blocks on otherwise cached pages. You can opt to bypass drupal's cache for the refresh callbacks for each block.
```

I have used this with a bit of jQuery like this:

- set it up to use a link
- a link will appear on the block which is ugly, use some css to hide it (display:none)
- use a simple jQuery onChange() to force the link to activate

  ```
  jQuery('#selector').onChange(function(){ jQuery('#refresh').click(); });
  ```

The specifics would depend on block names, etc.

Comment: But i want to load contents in FORM B based on selected value in either field of FORM A. ie if user selects value from first field in FORM A then all the fields under this first field within this form and also field under FORM B should be updated based on selected field.

Comment: So the question really isnt about ajax, but how to relate two forms on two different blocks, and base the options in one on the value of the other?

Comment: The 1st field in FORM A consists Taxonomy parent term.
The 2nd field in FORM A consists Taxonomy child term.

When user selects value from 1st field then in 2nd field all the child terms of selected parent are shown in 2nd field(Note: this is working fine), 

But Form B should also show all the contents having child terms of selected parent(Needs to be done).

Comment: Thats the sort of information that should be included in a question. This would be simplest using a Views block, Views block refresh module and a contextual filter... Assuming i now have ALL the information.

Comment: plz can you show some example???