# Add block fields as contextual filter in view

Tags: views, 7

Is it possible to add field from block into contextual filter?

There is a *custom block* listed on front page containing three drop down select list fields depending to one another.

> - First field contains taxonomy parent term.
> - Second field contains child term depends on above selected value.

I also have another block of view showing all the node titles having selected taxonomy term. Now my problem is that how can I add two fields(parent & child term fields) from first block as contextual filter in view.
Note that first block is a custom block developed in a custom module while the second block is a block in views.
So how is it possible? Anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [call external form in ajax callback](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/162899/call-external-form-in-ajax-callback)

Comment: @Geoff this is not duplicate, because in your suggested question both the blocks were developed in a custom module and there was a problem in ajax callback.
But in this question one block in a custom module while other block in a views and problem here is to add contextual filter into views.